# structure of mysql insert in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that I’m trying to use to upload zip files of photos.
The script should do these things, in this order:

1. Take an input of 4 variables for location, date, subject, and name of directory to use
2. Open a mysql connection
3. Handle a zip file
   1)      Upload the zip file
   2)      Unzip the file
   3)      Save the photos in the file to the specified directory
   4)      Save the url of each photo, as well some other info about the photo, to a mysql database.
4. Close the mysql connection
5. Confirm that everything functioned correctly.
6. Present the user the opportunity to upload another separate zip file with different variables.

As of right now, I’m able to get most of this done correctly. However, something is off about the structure of my code, and I’m not sure how to modify it. When I upload the first set, it works fine. However, if I try to upload a second set, a couple of things happen. The photos that have been uploaded so far end up getting entered into the mysql database again for each time that I try to upload another set.

Can anyone tell me how to correct this so that each individual image is inserted into the database once and only once?

```
<?php  // actual code for upload
$dirname = $_REQUEST['dirname'];
$taken = $_REQUEST['taken'];
$location = $_REQUEST['location'];
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$urldirectory = $_REQUEST['urldirectory'];

if(!(file_exists($dirname) && is_dir($dirname))) { // confirm that the directory exists, and that it is a directory
mkdir($dirname, 0777);
echo "the directory will be called ".$dirname;
} else {
echo "directory: " . $dirname;
} 

if($_FILES["zip_file"]["name"]) { // pull the nmae of the zip file from the upload
    $filename = $_FILES["zip_file"]["name"];
    $source = $_FILES["zip_file"]["tmp_name"];
    $type = $_FILES["zip_file"]["type"];

    $name = explode(".", $filename); //format the filename for a variable
    $accepted_types = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');
    foreach($accepted_types as $mime_type) {
            if($mime_type == $type) {
                    $okay = true;
                    break;
            } 
    }

    $continue = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false; // let user know if the zip file has not been uploaded
    if(!$continue) {
                $message = "The file you are trying to upload is not a .zip file. Please try again.";
    }
        $target_path = $dirname."/".$name; // get the $target_path variable to for the move_uploaded_file() function.

        if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) { // this block extracts the zip files and moves them to the $dirname directory

            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            $x = $zip->open($target_path);
            if ($x === true) {
                    $zip->extractTo($dirname."/"); 
                    $zip->close();
                    unlink($target_path);
            }

                    $message = "Your .zip file was uploaded and unpacked.";
                    //use glob to find all the files that have been unzipped into the directory, and then do a foreach loop that enters the image file locations into your mysql database
                    require_once 'connect.php';
                    echo '<html>'; 


                    echo '<html>'; 

                    $images = array(); // this clears the array by initializing between each reload of the page. Without this, each separate folder being uploaded would accumulate in the array and be uploaded multiple times. 
                    $images = scandir($dirname); //use scandir to find all the files that have been unzipped into the directory, and then do a foreach loop that enters the image file locations into your mysql database

                    foreach ($images as $value) {
                        if ($value!='.' && $value!='..' && $subjecttest=$subject) {
/*                                $url = trim($urldirectory)."/".trim($value);*/
                            echo '<img src="http://www.example.com/temp/' . $dirname . '/' . $value . '"< /img>';
                            $url = trim('http://www.example.com/temp/') . trim($dirname) . '/' . trim($value);
                            $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO pics (taken, location, subject, url) VALUES ('$taken', '$location', '$subject' , '$url');";

                                    if (mysql_query($insert_sql)) { 
                                                    echo "$value"." inserted successfully!";
                                            } else {        
                                                    echo "$value"." not inserted";
                                                    echo $insert_sql . '<BR>' . mysql_error();
                                            }

                                            } else {
                                                echo 'Please use unique info for each upload set'
                                            }

                                    unset($images); // destroys the $images variable, so it doesn't accumulate the next time you upload another folder. 
                                        }
                                        }
                            echo '</html>';


                                    } else {        
                    $message = "There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.";
            }
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR...nsitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
if($message) echo "<p>$message</p>";
if($taken) echo "<p>pictures taken on: " . $taken . "</p>";
if($subject) echo "<p>subject: " . $subject  . "</p>";
if($location) echo "<p>location: " . $location . "</p>";
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload2.php"> 
    <label for="dirname">Directory to use?: </label> <input name="dirname" size="20" type="text" value="<?php echo $dirname; ?>" /><br />
<label for="taken">When was this taken?:</label> <input name="taken" size="20" type="text" value="<?php echo $dirname; ?>" /><br />
<label for="location">Where was this taken?</label> <input name="location" size="20" type="text" /><br />
<label for="subject">subject?</label> <input name="subject" size="20" type="text" /><br />
<input type=hidden name="urldirectory" value="<?php echo "http://www.example.com/temp/".'$dirname;' ?>" />
<label>Choose a zip file to upload: <input type="file" name="zip_file" /></label>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's `$subjecttest`? You compare with it, but never set it.

Comment: An artifact from a previous attempt at solving this problem, and evidence that I need to clean up my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the source of your problem is here (line 53 and 54 by my count):

```
$images = array(); // this clears the array by initializing between each reload of the page. Without this, each separate folder being uploaded would accumulate in the array and be uploaded multiple times. 
$images = scandir($dirname); //use scandir to find all the files that have been unzipped into the directory, and then do a foreach loop that enters the image file locations into your mysql database
```

By using `scandir`, you retrieve not only the images you've just uploaded, but *all* previously uploaded images as well. Instead, you can read the filenames directly from the zip archive, in a manner similar to this:

```
$new_names = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$zip->numFiles; $i++) {
    $new_names[] = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

scandir will get all the files in your target directory, both the new ones extracted from the current zip file, and any previous files uploaded with other extractions as well. You should rather collect the names of the files in your zip specifically, and only insert values for them.

Comment: How would you recommend I do that?